# What causes the '' in ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ''] when you do re.findall('[\w]?', 'hello')

Tags: python, regex

What causes the `''` in `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '']` when you do `re.findall('[\w]?', 'hello')`.  I thought the result would be `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, without the last empty string.

Comment: note that the character class is superfluous in this case since you're only including one (meta)character. `'\w?'` is identical.

Comment: Also note that if you lose the `?` you'll get your expected result. The explanation is in the answer below.

Comment: And just for fun, `re.findall(r'[\w]?', '')` finds one too `['']`.

Comment: Can I join the upvotes party too please? Where do I vote?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The question mark in your regex (`'[\w]?'`) is responsible for the empty string being one of the returned results.

A question mark is a quantifier meaning "zero-or-one matches." You are asking for all occurrences of either zero-or-one "word characters". The letters satisfy the "-or-one word characters" match. The empty string satisfies the “zero word characters” match condition.

Change your regex to `'\w'` (remove the question mark and superfluous character class brackets) and the output will be as you expect.

Comment: also worth noting (and perhaps illustrative!) that `'\w??'` matches one or zero word characters but *prefers to match zero*. The output there is all empty strings!

Comment: If follow your explanation, the regex is just infinite, because there's unlimited number of "empty strings" in the end of the string. Why only one "empty string" is captured?

Comment: Precisely in order to prevent the infinite result you imagine, regexp engines behave as if there is *only one* empty string between each pair of characters, and before/after the first/last character. (Your regexp only matches the empty string at the end of the input, when used with `findall`, because in all other positions it has a choice between matching the empty string and matching a longer (nonempty) string, and it prefers to match a longer string.)

Comment: @nicael: Because regex quantifiers are greedy, so it only matches the empty string at the end of the input string.

Answer (score 5):

Regexes search through strings one character at a time. If a match is found at a character position the regex advances to the next part of the pattern. If a match is not found, the regex tries alternation (different variations) if available. If all alternatives fail, it backtracks and tries alternating the previous part and so on until either an entire match is found or all alternatives fail. This is why some seemingly simple regexes will match a string quickly, but fail to match in exponential time. In your example you only have one part to your pattern.

You are searching for `[\w]?`. The `?` means "**one** or **zero** of prior part" and is equivalent to `{0,1}`. Each of `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'` & `'o'` matches `[\w]{1}`, so the pattern advances and completes for each letter, restarting the regex at the beginning because you asked for all the matches, not just the first. At the end of the string the regex is still trying to find a match. `[\w]{1}` no longer matches but the alternative `[\w]{0}` does, so it matches `''`. Modern regex engines have a rule to stop zero-length matches from repeating at the same position. The regex tries again, but this time fails because it can't find a match for `[\w]{1}` and it has already found a match for `[\w]{0}`. It can't advance through the string because it is at the end, so it exits. It has run the pattern 7 times and found 6 matches, the last one of which was empty.

As pointed out in a comment, if your regex was `\w??` (I've removed `[` and `]` because they aren't necessary in your original regex), it means find **zero** or **one** (note the order has changed from before). It will return `''`, `'h'`, `''`, `'e'`, `''`, `'l'`, `''`, `'l'`, `''`, `'o'` & `''`. This is because it now prefers to find zero but it can't find two zero-length matches in a row without advancing.